# Scatter plot highchart symbol issue

Tags: highcharts, vuejs2

I am using scatter plot highcharts where i have dropdown (option1, option2, option3) and when i try to filter through option3 the marker.symbol is mixing with other symbols. Assume for option1(symbol:square), option2(symbol:circle),option3(symbol:diamond) and attached the screenshots below

`marker: {
                enabled:true,
                symbol: "square",
                lineWidth: 0
              }
marker: {
               enabled:true,
               symbol: "circle",
               lineWidth: 0
              },
marker: {
               enabled:true,
               symbol: "diamond",
               lineWidth: 0
              },`

The problem I am facing is, when i try to filter for option3 in the dropdown, chart is loading with diamond and square .

1) When select all the options in the dropdown, the chart looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQtZf.png)

2) When I select only option3(chat) the chart look like this , below we can see instead of diamond , i am getting square. Please help me on this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMmvr.png)

Comment: Could you reproduce it? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj